# Creating a POST policy and signing it for Browser based uploads to Amazon S3 in golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to implement browser based upload to amazon S3 from my client side(AngularJS), after some research i came to know that i have to create a policy and sign for POST request of S3.
By referring to  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html, i tried http://play.golang.org/p/3zn5fSDasK

```
package main
  import "fmt"
  import "encoding/base64"

  func main() {
     bytePolicy := []byte(`{ 
                "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
                "conditions": [
                         {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
                         ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
                         {"acl": "public-read"},
                         {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
                         ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
                         {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
                         ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
                         {"x-amz-credential":"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
                         {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
                         {"x-amz-date": "20130806T000000Z" }
                  ]
              }`)
        fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytePolicy))
 }
```

and i got the base64 encrypted value also.
Since the bytepolicy is a type of byte and accepting string as value the policy is hard coded. How can i change the values dynamically as like Javascript's template literals?? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or is there any other way i can create signed policy?

Comment: Your `bytePolicy` is created using a [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals), Go doesn't expand variables inside. Instead, Go has both text and html templates. The docs for the former have [an example](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template) that looks exactly like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options: generate a string using `fmt.Sprintf`, or use templates.

Formatting your own string with [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) is probably the fastest: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BbfCejRIiwA)

```
// The variables to set the contents to.
key := "mykey"
contentType := "text/plain"

// The "template". Use the proper % modifiers based on your variable types.
templateString := `{ 
                    "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
                    "conditions": [
                            {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
                            ["starts-with", "%s", "user/user1/"],
                            {"acl": "public-read"},
                            {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
                            ["starts-with", "%s", "image/"],
                            // etc...
                      ]
                }`

// Format the string.
filledTemplate := fmt.Sprintf(templateString, key, contentType)
fmt.Println(filledTemplate)

// Make a byte slice.
bytePolicy := []byte(filledTemplate)
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytePolicy))
```

The other, probably cleaner way is to use [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/): [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VvxoZi14Eng)

```
templateString := `{ 
                    "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
                    "conditions": [
                            {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
                            ["starts-with", "{{- .Key -}}", "user/user1/"],
                            {"acl": "public-read"},
                            {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
                            ["starts-with", "{{- .ContentType -}}", "image/"],
                            // Etc...
                      ]
                }`

type TemplateInfo struct {
    Key, ContentType string
}

myInfo := TemplateInfo{
    Key:         "mykey",
    ContentType: "text/plain",
}

t := template.Must(template.New("awsfields").Parse(templateString))

var out bytes.Buffer
if err := t.Execute(&out, myInfo); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(out.String())
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(out.Bytes()))
```